# Lock table in oracle database using JDBC driver

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to lock a table in my testing framework in order to trigger timeouts.  I am using the following code to lock the table.

```
String lock = "lock table "+ tableName +" in exclusive mode";
try {
        connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _username, _password);
        connection.setAutoCommit(false);  
        Statement stmt1=connection.createStatement();  
        stmt1.executeUpdate(lock);  

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After I have executed this I try to access the page and add an element to the account.  However it doesn't work, the lock doesn't seem to have occurred.  Any idea why this wouldn't work?  I am currently testing this in java and once I have executed that lock I am sleeping the thread while manually testing the page, could this be causing problems?

Thanks,
James

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The oracle's documentation say:

> You use the LOCK TABLE statement to lock entire database tables in a
>   specified lock mode so that you can share or deny access to them.. Row
>   share locks allow concurrent access to a table; they prevent other
>   users from locking the entire table for exclusive use. Table locks are
>   released when your transaction issues a commit or rollback.

So you need to start a transaction and maintain it. The following code maintains the table locked for one minute:

```
String lock = "lock table "+ tableName +" in exclusive mode";
try {
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(_url, _username, _password);
    connection.setAutoCommit(false);  
    Statement stmt1=connection.createStatement();  
    stmt1.execute(lock);  
    int i = 0;
    while (i<60) {            
        Thread.sleep(1000);    //Sleep one second
        i++;                   
    }
    connection.commit();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    connection.rollback();
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Is there no way that I can lock it and then leave it locked until I rollback?  I need to lock it while executing other java commands, and would prefer not to create a thread here.

Comment: Fair enough I guess I need to be more liberal when determining whether an answer is an 'answer'

Comment: Is this applicable in multi-thhreaded environment if each thread get a new connection object and interacts with DB

Comment: Since the lock is made in database at table level, if you have other threads accessing with new connections they must wait for table lock release.